# App Store Connect cannot add group to TestFlight build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a new build of my app in App Store Connect. When I go to TestFlight > Build # > Add Group (Group + button) It asks me to enter 'Export Compliance Information.' When I add this information add click on 'Start Internal Testing' the entire screen reloads. Then returning to the same build, I can see that no Groups have been added to this build. I am a member of this Group so I know the Group has not been added because the build is not released to TestFlight on my iOS device.

My friend who is also an Internal Tester is able to go through the same steps and this all works successfully for them. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by changing my role from 'Developer' to 'Admin' in App Store Connect.

Comment: App Manager (one step lower) would do as well: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Thanks for your response, But my role is admin.